# Use of $implicit do not pass value when using content projection

Tags: angular, ng-template, ng-content, ng-container

While playing with the concept of ng-template (html to to render), ng-container (work with ng-template for rendering) and ng-content (content projection), I'm having trouble to make use of $implicit value in a particular situation.

When the context is provided within `*ngTemplateOutlet` using a ng-container and content projection,the implicit value is not present.

Cannot figure out why, any idea ?

See bellow the code :

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->
<ng-template #inputTemplate let-labelDescription="inputLabel" let-defaultTagValue="inputValue">
  <label for="action">{{labelDescription}}</label><input id="idAction" value="{{defaultTagValue}}">
</ng-template>

<ng-template #buttonTemplate let-labelDescription="buttonLabel" let-defaultTagValue="buttonValue">
  <label for="action">label: {{labelDescription}}</label><h1><button id="idAction">my value : {{defaultTagValue}}</button></h1>
</ng-template>

<testing-componenet [id]="0" [description]="'send template button'">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="buttonTemplate; context: { buttonLabel:'LABEL_BUTTON', $implicit: '..data..'}"></ng-container>
</testing-componenet>
```

```js
// testing-component.component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'testing-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: "<p> {{id}} </p><p> {{description}} </p> <ng-content></ng-content>"
})
export class TestingComponentComponent {
    @Input( {required:true} )
    id!: number ;
    @Input( {required:true} )
    description!:string;
}
```

Result :

[image]

Should be :
[image]

Comment: Your second template expects a `buttonLabel` and `buttonValue`. So it should be `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="buttonTemplate; context: { buttonLabel:'LABEL_BUTTON', buttonValue: '..data..'}"></ng-container>`

Comment: If on the other hand you want to use `$implicit` there, you should write `<ng-template #buttonTemplate let-labelDescription="buttonLabel" let-defaultTagValue>`

Comment: @Pieterjan, that's it ! thanks ! Please provide as answer, i will validate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options.

Since your second template expects a `buttonLabel` and `buttonValue` template variable

```
<!-- let-labelDescription="buttonLabel" let-defaultTagValue="buttonValue" -->

<ng-template #buttonTemplate let-labelDescription="buttonLabel" let-defaultTagValue="buttonValue">
  <label for="action">label: {{labelDescription}}</label><h1><button id="idAction">my value : {{defaultTagValue}}</button></h1>
</ng-template>
```

You should use the following `ngTemplateOutlet` snippet

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="buttonTemplate; context: { buttonLabel:'LABEL_BUTTON', buttonValue: '..data..'}"></ng-container> <!-- not $implicit -->
```

---

On the other hand, you could use `$implicit` if you wanted to

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="buttonTemplate; context: { buttonLabel:'LABEL_BUTTON', $implicit: '..data..'}"></ng-container>
```

but then you have to pass in the following template

```
<ng-template #buttonTemplate let-labelDescription="buttonLabel" let-defaultTagValue> <!-- Remove ="buttonValue" -->
  <label for="action">label: {{labelDescription}}</label><h1><button id="idAction">my value : {{defaultTagValue}}</button></h1>
</ng-template>
```

### Making it more awesome

At the moment you're using `<ng-content>` which projects the `<ng-container>` and templateoutletdirective, and you're kinda lucky this works. A more slick way to do this is by writing a new directive

```
@Directive({ selector: 'testContent' })
export class TestContentDirective {
  constructor(testComponent: TestingComponentComponent, template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    testComponent.template = template;
  }
}
```

So now you can use your component [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kgdwss):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'testing-component',
  template: `
    <p> {{id}} </p>
    <p> {{description}} </p>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: { buttonLabel:'LABEL_BUTTON', buttonValue: '..data..'}"></ng-container>`,
})
export class TestingComponentComponent {
  @Input({ required: true }) id!: number;
  @Input({ required: true }) description!: string;
  template: TemplateRef<any> | null = null;
}

@Directive({ selector: '[testContent]' })
export class TestContentDirective {
  constructor(testComponent: TestingComponentComponent, template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    testComponent.template = template;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestingComponentComponent, TestContentDirective],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [TestingComponentComponent, TestContentDirective]
})
export class TestModule {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [TestModule],
  template: `
    <testing-component [id]="0" [description]="'send template button'">
      <ng-template testContent let-labelDescription="buttonLabel" let-defaultTagValue="buttonValue">
        <label for="action">label: {{labelDescription}}</label><h1><button id="idAction">my value : {{defaultTagValue}}</button></h1>
      </ng-template>
    </testing-component>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

To take things even further you can write it [using the structural directive notation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4tuvhk)

```
<testing-component [id]="0" [description]="'send template button'">
  <div *testContent="let labelDescription=buttonLabel; let defaultTagValue=buttonValue">
    <label for="action">label: {{labelDescription}}</label><h1><button id="idAction">my value : {{defaultTagValue}}</button></h1>
  </div>
</testing-component>
```

Or you could also [use a default template using the coalescing operator](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kycuzo):

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template ?? defaultTemplate; ..."></ng-container>
<ng-template #defaultTemplate let-labelDescription="buttonLabel" let-defaultTagValue="buttonValue">
  <label for="action">label: Default description</label><h1><button id="idAction">my value: Default value</button></h1>
</ng-template>
```

So the conclusion is that you have 2 options. You can either use `<ng-content select="[slot1]">` or you can use structural directives, assign the template to the main generic component, and project it while passing information from inside the generic component to wherever you're using it. I always tend to opt for the template approach, since it's more flexible and easier to pass data to the parent. I use it all the time. [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/datatable/src) an example component and [here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/advanced/datatables) how to use it.

### Adding a template context guard

If you would take a look now at where you use your structural directive, you'd see that the template variables you receive have the `any` type

[image: Structural directive variables with any type]

You can solve this by adding a `ngTemplateContextGuard` static field to your directive ([DOCS](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#improving-template-type-checking-for-custom-directives)):

```
@Directive({ selector: '[testContent]' })
export class TestContentDirective {
  constructor(testComponent: TestingComponentComponent, template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    console.log('received a template');
    testComponent.template = template;
  }
  
  public static ngTemplateContextGuard(
    dir: TestContentDirective,
    ctx: any
  ): ctx is BsTestTemplateContext {
    return true;
  }
}

export class BsTestTemplateContext {
  // public $implicit: TData = null!;
  buttonLabel!: string;
  buttonValue!: string;
}
```

Result:

[image]

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kjunlp), but they don't show tooltips in templates.

Comment: What an answer ! Far beyond my expectation, I can go deeper in those concepts !!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Pieterjan, error comes  from the named variable, bellow code allow to use the $implicit value correctly

```html
<ng-template 
  #buttonTemplate 
  let-labelDescription="buttonLabel"
  let-defaultTagValue><!--avoid affectation if need to use $implicit in a template pass with content projection -->
```